# Sum function on two different Tables in single select query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, sqlite

I have 2 tables and I want to get the Dataset from single query to show it in a chart.
But I am getting the Error in execution. There is only year and expYear and Month and Exp Month are the column may having common data. every row is having its year and month fields.

here is the query I was trying:

```
select 
  t.transExpense
  g.grocExpense
from
  (Select sum(traexpense) as transExpense from 
              transportExpense where Year="2014") t,
  (Select sum(groexpense) as grocExpense from 
              groceryExpense where expYear="2014") g
```

Please help.

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma after `t.transExpense`.

However, to return a single value, you don't need to put the subqueries into the FROM clause; you can use them directly in the SELECT as scalar subqueries:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT SUM(traexpense)
        FROM transportExpense
        WHERE Year = '2014'
       ) AS transExpense,
       (SELECT SUM(groexpense)
        FROM grocExpense
        WHERE expYear = '2014'
       ) AS grocExpense;
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. It make sense to get something optimize. Sometime we forget small things like a comma to spoil our day.

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma between your selected fields:

```
select 
t.transExpense,  -- << right there
g.grocExpense
from
(Select sum(traexpense) as transExpense from transportExpense where Year="2014") t,
(Select sum(groexpense) as grocExpense from groceryExpense where expYear="2014") g
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using JOIN Query. Something like :

```
SELECT  sum(t.traexpense) as t.transExpense,  sum(g.groexpense) as g.grocExpense
from transportExpense t LEFT JOIN groceryExpense g ON t.fieldname=g.fieldname
where g.expYear=2014 and t. Year=2014
```

If your table does not have the any common field for joining you can use t.Year and g.expYear for joining.